# Why are these Object Properties undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access the properties of an object returned from my php script using `json_encode` like so:

php

```
echo json_encode(array(
  'person_id' => $personID,
  'job_id' => $jobID)
);
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  cache: false,
  type: "POST"
}).done(function(sData){
  console.log(sData);
  console.log(sData.job_id);
  console.log(sData.person_id);
});
```

Output:

```
{"person_id":1,"job_id":1}
undefined
undefined
```

What's going on here? Why can't I access these properties?

**UPDATE:**

For any future visitors, this is a mistake I've made MANY, MANY times before (leaving out `dataType`) and will most certainly make again.

It can be especially confusing because when you examine your server response in Chrome Dev Tools, it is automatically parsed as a JSON object (in the PREVIEW tab).

[image]

It's nice that Chrome does this, so that you can easily inspect your response data, however the same is not true for your javascript code, you WILL NEED to declare the proper `dataType` of the response so that your code can interpret the data as an object and not a string.

Comment: someone's mommy didn't love them enough...

Comment: ^^^ LOL........serial downvoting again? haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.ajax` doesn't evaluate the response as JSON by default.  you have to pass `dataType: 'json'`

This should do it

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(sData){
        console.log(sData);
        console.log(sData.job_id);
        console.log(sData.person_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP returns a string value. This value has to be parsed into a javascript object. Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   cache: false,
   type: "POST"
 }).done(function(sData){
   sData = JSON.parse(sData);
   console.log(sData);
   console.log(sData.job_id);
   console.log(sData.person_id);
});
```

JSON is not an object/associative array but a string representation of one. JSON allows you to send object across languages but it must be parsed from the string into the value in that language. In jQuery you can just set the `dataType` but the important note is that in any language you have to parse the JSON.

Comment: If you are going to downvote a correct answer please provide an explanation.

Comment: I disagree with the method used. While it does solve the problem, it would more more appropriate to set the proper content type and/or datatype. The downvote was before you added the additional line mentioning dataType.

Comment: @KevinB You are right that it isn't the easiest way to solve the problem. I was trying to point out the real problem here. A.O. was trying to use a JSON string like an object. This answer could help people that have a similar problem. Regardless it is not an incorrect answer. Cfreak's answer is better but that doesn't make mine wrong.

Answer (score -2):

`sData` - string

use `jQuery.parseJSON` or `jQuery.getJSON()`

Comment: It would go a long way if you could add some detailed explanation to your "answer"